# how to enable/add scrollbar in android phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, scrollbar

I created dynamic list using android phonegap application.Now I want to add scrollbar for that list. I used html and javascript/jquery for creating dynamic list in android phonegap application.how to add scrollbar dynamically to that list?
Is it possible add scrollbar in android phonegap application?

please guide me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile WebKit (iOS and Android, etc) does not provide a native way to scroll content inside a fixed width/height element, but many libraries can help you with that issue.

I use the [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to scroll the content in my PhoneGap app. It's a very lightweight framework, only focuses on the scroll problem of mobile WebKit browser or WebViews, and it works perfect.

Here is a simple [example](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/).